# Why does OS X 10.7.4 want me to move my app to the trash?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

We have an app for OS X which we distribute via our own website, it is bundled in a preference pane and comes with 3 daemons. Since 10.7.4 One of the daemon doesn't run anymore and OS X says this:

> YZ can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash.

The console isn't very helpful to me, yet, providing this error message:

```
23.06.12 18:22:15,284 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: 
([0x0-0x176176].com.bananaglue.control.helper[1902]) 
Exited: Killed: 9
```

Same on OS X 10.8. We haven't changed anything and it used to run without errors before.

Any hints how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the following explanation:

> The app’s authorization has been revoked. Although this app was signed by an identified developer, the certificate for this app has been revoked. There may be a problem with it. The app cannot be opened.

Quote by [Krystof Vasa](http://help.fuelcollective.com/discussions/problems/2857-cannot-run-pochade) from Fuel Collective:

> Apple is for some (to-me unknown) reason enabling the 10.8's Gate Keeper feature already in 10.7.4. Gate Keeper is supposed to let you prevent non-AppStore or non-signed apps from launching. **Gate Keeper** settings are in **System Preferences > Security & Privacy** - make sure it's set to **Anywhere**. If this doesn't help either, here's a guide how to disable Gate Keeper, which shouldn't be running in 10.7.4 anyway.

Disable GateKeeper by running the following command:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Maybe you can contact Krystof Vasa and ask how they exactly fixed the problem.

Comment: You could also run `sudo spctl --assess --verbose=4 <path to app>` to see if it will explain what it thinks is wrong. Similarly, `codesign -v -vvv <path to app>`.

Comment: the assessment results in this error: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED. I know what to do now. Thanks to both of you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

There is a less "sledge hammer" way to fix this. I ran into this problem today and it occurred because of the combination of two things: the quarantine extended attribute is set on the application bundle and the signature is broken such that typing:

```
codesign -vv <app bundle>
```

results in:

```
<app bundle>: code has no resources but signature indicates they must be present
```

You can see the extended attributes by typing ls -la@ in the terminal. It will show you "com.apple.quarantine" on the file.

Rather than disable Gatekeeper, you can use the following terminal command to remove all of the extended file attributes:

```
xattr -c <app bundle>
```

I'm googling around to see if I can figure out exactly how the signature is broken so I can fix it (I'm a new developer at the company that makes this thing) and ran across this question.

Disabling Gatekeeper altogether is not something I'd recommend. When Gatekeeper warns you about something, you get additional information about it and its possible that it could save you from accidentally running something you don't want to run.

Comment: Wow! `xattr -c <PATH>` did it! Thank you so much!